# How small can you make a model realistically?

Tags: optimization, retopology, compression

all! I have a model that I want to add to a THREE.js scene on the web, so making it as light as possible is the main goal. I'm not an expert, so I have no idea how 'small' one could make a model. Right now, I have a model with ~65k verts and faces, with ~129,000 tris. The smallest I've been able to get it so far is ~500kb with Draco compression (.glb format). without compression, it sits at about 5MB. How small can one reasonably get a model with Draco?

[image]

Comment: What's your export format (fbx, collada, obj. gltf)?

Comment: .glb is the format I'm aiming for. I thought I put that. ‍♂️